# Rollover delay for Map markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

We had a developer work-up a piece of javascript for animating markers on a map for us. See http://luniablue.com/clients/endowment for it's current state.

The issue I'm having, is that the rollover is too sensitive and I want there to be a 1sec pause before executing the rollover function.  From what I've read, I need to declare a setTimeout() function, but I'm not clear on where to insert that.

I have tried every place that I can see and I've had no luck except in breaking the script.  I'm sure it's something stupid simple, but javascript isn't my stong point. Can anyone help me out?

Here's the code:

```
var firstEntry = true;
var lastOn = '';

function showAllPins() {
    if ($('#communities').hasClass('theMouseIsOff')) {
        var citiesArr = [];
        $('.pin').each( function () { 
            citiesArr.push(this.id);
            $('#'+this.id).hide();
        });
        var stillHidden = citiesArr.length;
        while (stillHidden > 0) {
            var a = Math.floor(Math.random()*citiesArr.length);
            if ($('#'+citiesArr[a]).is(':hidden')) {
                $('#'+citiesArr[a]).show().delay(Math.floor(Math.random()*900)).animate({
                    opacity: 1,
                    top: '+=40',
                }, Math.floor(Math.random()*900), 'easeOutBounce');
                stillHidden--;
            }
        }
        firstEntry = true;
        $('#communities').removeClass('theMouseIsOff');
    }
}
function showPin(relid){
    lastOn = relid;
    if ($('#communities').hasClass('theMouseIsOff')) $('#communities').removeClass('theMouseIsOff');
    if (firstEntry == true) {
        $("#communities div[id!=" + relid + "].pin").animate({
            opacity: 0,
            top: '-=40',
        }, 500);
        firstEntry = false;
    } else {
        $("#communities div[id=" + relid + "].pin").animate({
            opacity: 1,
            top: '+=40',
        }, 500, 'easeOutBounce');
    }
}
function removeLastPin() {
    $('#communities').addClass('theMouseIsOff');
    $("#communities div[id=" + lastOn + "].pin").animate({
        opacity: 0,
        top: '-=40',
    }, 500);
    setTimeout('showAllPins()',600);
}

$(document).ready( function () {
    $('.pin').mouseenter( function () {
        relid = $(this).attr('rel');
        showPin(relid);
    }).mouseleave( function () { removeLastPin() });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pin').each(function() {
         var selector = '#' + $(this).data('tooltip-id');
         Tipped.create(this, $(selector)[0], { skin: 'light', hook: { target: 'topmiddle', tooltip: 'bottomleft'}});
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you see:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('.pin').mouseenter( function () {
        relid = $(this).attr('rel');
        showPin(relid);
    }).mouseleave( function () { removeLastPin() });
});
```

You can change it to:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('.pin').mouseenter( function () {
        relid = $(this).attr('rel');
        setTimeout(function(){showPin(relid)}, 1000);
    }).mouseleave( function () { removeLastPin() });
});
```

By changing the `showPin()` function to execute after a timeout, the pin should appear after the specified interval.

**Update:**

If you would like the function only to run if the mouseleave hasn't occurred during the specified interval, you can clear the interval on mouseleave like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pin').mouseenter(function() {
        relid = $(this).attr('rel');
        var awaiting = setTimeout(function() {
            showPin(relid)
        }, 1000);
    }).mouseleave(function() {    
        removeLastPin();
        clearInterval(awaiting);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I think I wasn't including the 'function()' part. Although this works in delaying the animation, I'm thinking this isn't the solution to my problem. The animation plays 1sec after the hover, but I need it to play if you've hovered for 1sec. This should keep the animation from going crazy when you're trying to rollover the marker you want, but you accidentally rollover other markers on the way. Do I need a timer variable? How would I do that correctly?

Comment: @lbweb see update.  You may have more trouble with repeating animations depending on the animation functions. I can't be positive though without seeing it in action!